# C++ threads and variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a problem within the program that I write. I have functions returning pointers and within the main() I want to run them in threads.

I'm able to execute the functions in threads:

```
double* SplitFirstArray_1st(double *arr0){
    const UI arrSize = baseElements/4;
    std::cout << "\n1st split: \n";
    double *arrSplited1=nullptr;
    arrSplited1 = new double [arrSize];
    for(UI i=0; i<arrSize; i++){
        arrSplited1 = arr0;
    }

    for(UI j=0; j< arrSize; ++j){
        std::cout << arrSplited1[j] << " ";
        }
    return arrSplited1;
    delete [] arrSplited1, arr0;
```

}

in main()

```
std::thread _th1(SplitFirstArray_1st, rootArr);
                _th1.join();
```

The above is not what I'm after. I have another pointer:

```
*arrTh1=nullptr;
```

I would like to use it in a thread so it would be assigned with the value returned by my function SplitFirstArray_1st

```
arrTh1 = SplitFirstArray_1st(xxx);
```

Is such action is possible to be executed in a tread ?

Comment: `delete [] arrSplited1, arr0;` ... that's unusual.  What do you expect that to do?

Comment: @Eljay Doesn't matter because it's unreachable code anyway.

Comment: Hi, it shouldn't be there. That's "rubbish". Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question when you made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Don't return the variable, pass a pointer to the variable and set the value at what this points too.

i.e.:

```
void set_int(int* toset) {
  *toset = 4;
}
```

This works fine with things that are already pointers:

```
void set_ptr(int** toset) {
  *toset = new int[4];
  // ...
  *toset[0] = 2;
}
```

You can know the data is safe to use if the function has returned.

Completely unrelated note:

```
  return foo;
  // No point placing code here unless you used goto as it won't get executed.
  // Also: don't use goto.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
std::thread _th1([&]() { arrTh1 = SplitFirstArray_1st(rootArr); });
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks. I will definitely look into this.

Comment: `std::async` might even be a better solution in simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

Functions which start the thread cannot return values in a normal way. Therefore they should be declared as  `void`.

Common way is to assign a protected global variable. You should protect one with mutexes (or other methods) to avoid races.

```
mutex m;
double *arrTh1 = nullptr;


double* aSplitFirstArray_1st(double *arr0){
    ...
    m.lock();
    arrTh1 = arrSplited1;
    m.unlock();
}
```

When you use the pointer in other threads (including the main one), you need to protect the usage as well with the same mutex (or choose other methods).

and please, do **not** delete arrSopited1 and arr0. it will make the arrTh1 pointer unusable.

Note, if you use `async` functions, you could use `futures` to return values.

Comment: Since when is it a common way to have global variables? Also, it's spelled `future`.